# Trying to zero out html number input fields using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I have a form and I'm trying to have a button to zero out all the fields. Can't use a 'reset' type button, as there are proper default values there, populated externally.

It's incredibly basic, and I've stripped out any complication I can think of, but it isn't working. It's generated by a jinja template. When I click, however, absolutely nothing happens. No feedback in the logs, no change in the input field numbers. What amI missing?

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
        <script>
      function zero_out() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("itemCount").value=0;
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="post">
                    <label for="thing">thing</label>
                    <input type="number"  pattern="\d*"
                      name="thing" style="width: 40px;"
                      class="itemCount"
                      placeholder="0"
                      value=""></input>
                    <br />
           ...
        <button onclick="zero_out()" type="button" class="button">ZERO</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You can get the value of input when fire the zero_out function,then check the value of input ,if the value meet some condition,then do something ,or do other things?

Answer (score 0):

Just reset it with looping for collections of `getElementsByClassName` like this:

```js
function zero_out() {
  let items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemCount");
  Array.from(items).forEach((elm)=>{
    elm.value = 0;
  });
}
```

---

Full code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function zero_out() {
           let items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemCount");
           Array.from(items).forEach((elm)=>{
              elm.value = 0;
           });
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="thing">thing</label>
        <input type="number" pattern="\d*" name="thing" style="width: 40px;" class="itemCount" placeholder="0" value="5" />
        <label for="thing2">thing 2</label>
        <input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="thing2" style="width: 40px;" class="itemCount" placeholder="0" value="3" />
        <br />
        <button onclick="zero_out()" type="button" class="button">ZERO</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're only resetting one input, just use `document.querySelector` to get the element. (`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` of all elements with the specified class.)

```js
document.querySelector('input.itemCount').value = '0';
```